# Case-control study, odds ratio, logistic regression in Stata

Tags: logistic, stata, odds-ratio, case-control-study

I am very excited to be on this forum. I am new to biostatistics and have a question regarding my case-control study, for which I am using STATA for data analysis.

All my patients are diabetic. Some are on Metformin, and some are not. Likewise, some have respiratory infections, and some don't. My cases are diabetic patients with respiratory infection, and controls are the diabetic patients without respiratory infection. The exposure variable is Metformin.

I need to clarify if I am right or wrong about the following:

For this type of study, if I do a case-control odds ratio, it will be a crude or unadjusted odds ratio because STATA doesn't know if all these patients have diabetes. Correct? (In STATA, the case variable is Respiratory infection, and the Exposed variable is Metformin.)

In order to tell STATA I am doing it for patients who have diabetes, I would have to do a logistic regression with respiratory infection as the dependent variable and Metformin and diabetes as independent variables. It will also give me an adjusted odds ratio. Correct?

Comment: Feel free to improve the title further. (The original one was entirely uninformative.)